# wordpress Redirect old urls to new url

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, nginx, redirect

Hi I want to change my link structure in myy wordpress based website.

**My old link structure** is `www.mydomain.com/%post_id%/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`.

**My new url structure will be**: `www.mydomain.com/%postname%/`.

Also I am using  nginx webserver .

How can ı do redirect my old urls to new.

Comment: I'd suggest you look in the wordpress codex, specifically clean urls, before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rewrite rule in nginx :

```
rewrite /[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.+)$ /$1 permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to update the permalink structure in the reading section of the admin panel... Wordpress will handle the rest.

Comment: by links in google do you mean search results pointing to your page from google?

Comment: Try this plug in https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ I would install it and then update your permalinks